# How to prove a $d$-regular bipartite graph is $d$-edge colourable by using Konig theorem

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, coloring, discrete-optimization, bipartite-graphs

**Problem:** Prove that a $d$-regular bipartite graph is $d$-edge colourable using Konig-Egervary theorem

> If the the graph $G$ is bipartite then the size of max-matching equals
> to the size of min-vertex-cover

Here is my proof for the problem:
Create a Matching:
Apply Kőnig's theorem to find a maximum matching M in G. Since G is d-regular, each vertex in U and V is incident to exactly d edges in the matching.

Vertex Cover:
By Kőnig's theorem, the size of the maximum matching is equal to the size of the minimum vertex cover. Let C be a minimum vertex cover in G.

Coloring:
Now, we can use the vertices in U - C as one color class and the vertices in V ∩ C as the other color class. Since each vertex in U is adjacent to exactly one vertex in V in the matching M, and vice versa, the resulting coloring is proper.

Specifically, each vertex in U - C has all its neighbors in V ∩ C, and each vertex in V ∩ C has all its neighbors in U - C. Therefore, the coloring is proper, and each vertex is assigned one of the d colors.

I hope that you can help me to check and indicate if there is anything wrong

Comment: (1) The coloring is incomplete: there are vertices neither in $U-C$ nor in $V\cap C$. (2) It is a vertex coloring, not an edge coloring. (3) Probably the right Kőnig's theorem to use here is the one that says that every $d$-regular bipartite graph has a perfect matching, not the one you're using.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I mean there is any way that we can use the min-vertex-cover to solve this problem?

Comment: Not except by using that to prove the other Kőnig's theorem that I cited.